# Drupal 8: How do i fix the irritating error message "Unable to install advertisement, already exist in active configuration"?

Tags: php, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I'm new to Drupal programming but I have experienced a few problems.
Every time I uninstall a module and I want to install it again.

I get this error message:

> Unable to install advertisement, 
>   core.entity_form_display.node.advertisement.default,
>   core.entity_view_display.node.advertisement.default,
>   core.entity_view_display.node.advertisement.teaser,
>   field.field.node.advertisement.body, node.type.advertisement already
>   exist in active configuration.

What did I already do?

- With drush cache-clear / cache-rebuild **No result**
- In drupal self cache-clear **No result**
- And even dropt the drupal database /( it works but it is kind of annoying to do it every time.) **Result but a lot of work**

So I think I know where the problem is (Database tables), but how do I fix it in a fast and easy way?

Comment: Also see [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164612/how-do-i-remove-a-configuration-object-from-the-active-configuration) (and its answers).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Drush

```
drush config-delete module_name.settings
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem with a simple Drupal command, 
 **this requires the drupal console**. *What you can find [here!](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/index.html)*

All i had to do is to type in 2 commands

> - drupal module:uninstall advertisement
> - drupal module:install --overwrite-config advertisement

Comment: `--overwrite-config` is no longer an option for `module:install`. You have to use `config:delete` to remove the config. See my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [config:delete](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/commands/config-delete.html) command in the [Drupal console](https://drupalconsole.com/):

`drupal config:delete active CONFIG.TO.DELETE`

e.g.

`drupal config:delete active system.menu.devel`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a variation of the question about "[How do I remove a configuration object from the active configuration?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164612/how-do-i-remove-a-configuration-object-from-the-active-configuration)".

As per one of the answers there, I'd try to use this code in `hook_uninstall` to resolve the `core.entity_form_display.node.advertisement.default` part of your errors:
    Drupal::configFactory()->reset('core.entity_form_display.node.advertisement.default');

Then repeat (4 times?) for the other parts of your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the config files from

```
config/install
```

to

```
config/optional
```